# Chemical kinetics with the reaction of tert-butyl bromide with azide ion

Tags: reaction-mechanism, kinetics

> The reaction of tert-butyl bromide with azide ion in aqueous solution
>   is proposed to proceed by the following mechanism:
>
> $\ce{(CH3)3CBr(aq) <=>(CH3)3C+(aq) + Br–(aq)}$
>
> $\ce{(CH3)3C+(aq) + N3–(aq) \to (CH3)3CN3(aq)}$
>
> Assuming that $\ce{(CH3)3C+ (aq)}$ achieves a steady-state concentration, but making no further assumptions about the relative magnitudes of the three rate constants,
>   what is the rate law for this reaction, where $k_1$ is the forward
>   reaction rate of the first equation, $k_{-1}$ is the reverse reaction
>   rate of the first equation, and $k_2$ is the forward reaction rate of
>   the second equation?
>
> (A) $\ce{k_1[(CH3)3CBr]}$
>
> (B) $\ce{k_2[(CH3)3CBr][N3-]}$
>
> (C) $\ce{\displaystyle\frac{k_1k_2[(CH3)3CBr][N3-]}{k_{-1}[Br-]}}$
>
> (D) $\ce{\displaystyle\frac{k_1k_2[(CH3)3CBr][N3-]}{k_{-1}[Br-] + k2[N3-]}}$

**My thoughts:** First of all, I read that $\ce{(CH3)3C+ (aq)}$ is a steady state concentration, which meant that $\frac{d\ce{[(CH3)3C+ (aq)}]}{dt} = 0,$ which prompted me to write out differential equations for each reactant. Thus, I got a system of differential equations:
$$\frac{d\ce{[(CH3)3CBr (aq)}]}{dt} =-\frac{k_1}{k_{-1}}\ce{[(CH3)3CBr (aq)}]$$
$$0=\frac{d\ce{[(CH3)3C+ (aq)}]}{dt} = -\frac{d\ce{[(CH3)3CBr (aq)}]}{dt} - \frac{d\ce{[(CH3)3CN3 (aq)}]}{dt} = \frac{k_1}{k_{-1}}\ce{[(CH3)3CBr (aq)}] -k_2 \frac{d\ce{[(CH3)3CN3 (aq)]}}{dt}$$
$$\frac{d\ce{[Br- (aq)}]}{dt} = -\frac{d\ce{[(CH3)3CBr (aq)}]}{dt} = \frac{k_1}{k_{-1}}\ce{[(CH3)3CBr (aq)}]$$
$$\frac{d\ce{[N3- (aq)}]}{dt} = -k_2\ce{[N3-(aq)]}$$

But I was unsure of how to use these differential equations to actually find the rate law. Could anyone provide any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really don't have to write all that differential equations.

Note: I'll write all my steps on a paper, since MathJax formatting is a little time-taking at the moment.

Consider the rate laws for the two reactions:
[image]

Since the $\ce{[(CH3)3C+]}$ isn't changing with time, we get
[image]

From which, you get

[image]

Plugging these in the Rate2 which I mentioned, you will get,
[image]

Which is the same as what's given in option (D).

I hope I have satisfied your queries.

Comment: Sorry, but how did you get your first rate law?

Comment: Those rate laws are directly derived from the reaction. For example, in an elementary reaction: $$\ce{mA + nB -> C}$$ The rate law would be $$Rate=[A]^m+[B]^n$$

Comment: According to my book rate would be $k[A]^m [B]^n$ is that just a typo on your part? Additionally, how did you derive the rate law for reactions in equilibrium?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, that plus was not meant to be. (I cant edit that comment now, but I think you get it)

Comment: You should really take a look at [this](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) so you can correctly format your future posts.

Comment: @Display Name, for reactions at equilibrium, consider it has two reactions, one forward and one backward. Suppose for the reaction: $$\ce{mA + nB <=>[K_1][K_2] pC + qD}$$ We consider the rate of reaction as difference between the forward and backward rates. In that way, you will get the rate law to be: $$Rate=K_2[C]^p[D]^q-K_1[A]^m[B]^n$$

Comment: @PrittBalagopal Wouldn't the rate be the negative of what you wrote, because we are measuring the rate of formation of product, not reactant?

Comment: No, rate of reaction is defined as $$\text{Rate}=\frac{d\text{[Reactant]}}{dx}$$